# UITapGestureRecognizer selector not being invoked

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

Inside of my main window's root view controller class, I have set a UITapGestureRecognizer property. I've added this property to an image property through the addGestureRecognizer method during the call to the overridden viewDidLoad function. I have also set image.isUserInteractionEnabled to true.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   image.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
   image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

   self.view.addSubview(image)
}

var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imagePressed(_ :)))
```

Sadly, this does not result in imagePressed() being called when run. What's confusing me is the fact that the following code produces the intended result.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(imagePressed(_ :)))
   image.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
   image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

   self.view.addSubview(image)
}
```

So my question is, why does the UITapGestureRecognizer's selector not get invoked during the first case?

Using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: If what you posted as code is correct, how would you expect the first attempt to work? You `tap` declaration is not in any function! It **belongs** in *viewDidLoad()*.

Comment: Tap is a property of my view controller class

Comment: I can be wrong, but I've never seen nor heard of making a gesture recognizer a property of a view. I don't think it can be done.

Comment: Do you know why though? I mean, like you said, all examples that I have seen have shown the recognizer being created locally, but I want to know what the difference is between the two cases.

Comment: I'd guess it's - at the very least - related to variable scope. Consider this, how could an *instance* of a gesture attach itself to a *class* that hasn't loaded? (I'm sure more deeply knowledgable devs are laughing at this comment, but nearly 40 years in IT means I have my ways of converting "top-down" into OOP.) In other words, the earliest event in a UIViewController's life is viewDidLoad - why would expect everything you define "above" it to simply work? Yes, I'd hope the compiler would stop most things, but maybe it won't. If *self* isn't there yet, how do you attach something to it?

Comment: But self is already completely initialized, isn't it? The call to a method - in this case viewDidLoad() - of my viewController proves that it has been through the initialization process, since there would be no other way to access this method without a fully initialized instance of its containing class.

Comment: @modest_mildew, did you solve this yet?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is `addGestureRecognizer`.
Try to change your `viewDidLoad` to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(imagePressed(_ :)))
    image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    self.view.addSubview(image)

    image.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

Comment: Oh oops. That's what I intended to write, so the question still stands

Comment: So, Did you updated it? but `imagePressed` still not invoke?

Comment: Well, my actual code had the correct syntax so yah, imagePressed still isn't being invoked.

Comment: Can you try `addGestureRecognizer` after `addSubview`? Like as my answers do?

Comment: Yeah, just tried that and first case still doesn't work and the second case still does

Answer (score 1):

For future readers:

The first case does not work because `tap` is instantiated before the view controller's view is loaded, despite being written after the function declaration. Before `viewDidLoad()` is called, `self.view` is `nil`, and because `UITapGestureRecognizer` relies on the view, the gesture recognizer doesn't work.

Main takeaway: Both create *and* add gesture recognizers *after* your view controller's view has been added to the view hierarchy.